# I need to give a warning if a property in my for in loop is lower then 1000

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I made a code where I used a for in loop and what I can't figure out is that in the array:laptops.

If 'voorraad' is under the 1000  there should come ---WARNING--- next to the 1000

something like this image.

[image: screenshot]

so when its lower then 1000 there should come the warning.

In my code I tried if statement but its not working.

Did I put it wrong or should I use another code?

MY CODE ..>>

```
var laptops = new Array();
laptops['macbook'] = {
   'model': 'air',
   'voorraad': 2000,
   'prijs': 1090,
};

laptops['asusbook'] = {
   'model': 'wind',
   'voorraad': 1000,
   'prijs': 990
};
laptops['dellbook'] = {
   'model': 'fire',
   'voorraad': 987,
   'prijs': 890
};
for (var merk in laptops) {
   document.write("<br>Merk: " + merk);
   for (var property in laptops[merk]) {
      document.write('<br>' + property + ":" + laptops[merk][property])
   }
}
if (voorraad < 1000) {
   console.write("---WAARSCHUWING---")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood you wanted to replicate the Image that you provided so you wanna move the if statement into the inner-loop.Check the `property` is `voorraad` and the `laptops[merk].voorraad`(this would give you the numerical value) is less than 1000

```js
  var laptops = new Array();
  laptops["macbook"] = {
    model: "air",
    voorraad: 2000,
    prijs: 1090
  };

  laptops["asusbook"] = {
    model: "wind",
    voorraad: 1000,
    prijs: 990
  };
  laptops["dellbook"] = {
    model: "fire",
    voorraad: 987,
    prijs: 890
  };
  for (var merk in laptops) {
    document.write("<br />Merk: " + merk);
    for (var property in laptops[merk]) {
      document.write("<br />" + property + ":" + laptops[merk][property]);
      if (property === "voorraad" && laptops[merk].voorraad < 1000) {
        document.write("---WAARSCHUWING---");
      }
      console.log();
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much that is what i could not figure out u helped me so much,
i appreciate it